# move_uploaded_file() throwing error

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, upload

OK, so very simple upload script from w3schools, I have tried to implement but I keep getting an error message.

For reference I am using WordPress and required to create custom upload method so I cannot use custom fields etc..

**HTML section regarding this:**

```
<form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="frontImage" id="frontImage">
```

**PHP side of things:**

```
$target_dir = home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/survey/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["frontImage"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["frontImage"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }

// Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
// Check file size
        if ($_FILES["frontImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
// Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["frontImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["frontImage"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
```

**Okay so the error I am getting is:**

```
"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."
```

This means that move_uploaded_file() section failed.

**If I print_r($_FILES) I get:**

```
Array
(
    [frontImage] => Array
        (
            [name] => Everest_kalapatthar_crop.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHw9BcP
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 93053
        )

)
```

Is there any reason why this is not working?

Comment: What is *$target_dir* ? Is it the correct path to your directory? If yes make sure that the folder permissions are set to *0777*

Comment: Output `$target_dir` make sure it's valid.

Comment: @EM-Creations both target_dir and target_file are correct paths

Answer (score 0):

Test if your target directory actually exists writable using this code.

If your target directory is not writable, on a Mac, you can run this in the terminal.

`ls -lah /full/path/to/the/survey/directory`

and check the group and owner, it should be owned by `_www` like the rest of the directories in your website. If your Apache user is different, adjust as needed.

If it's not, then run these commands:
`sudo chown _www:_www /full/path/to/the/survey/directory/`
`sudo chmod 0755 /full/path/to/the/survey/directory/`

```
<?php

$target_dir = home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/survey/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["frontImage"]["name"]);

// check if dir is writable    
if ( !is_writable($target_dir)) {
    echo $target_dir . ' is not writable';
}
else {
    // proceed to write the file there
    // either set a boolean flag $writable = 1 or 
    // insert into if/else chain
}

// check if dir exists
if (!file_exists($target_dir)){
    echo $target_dir . ' does not exist';
}
else {
    // proceed with the rest of your logic
    // either set a boolean flag $dirExists = 1 or
    // insert this into your if/else chain
}
```

Comment: it says is not writable

Comment: it needs to be writable by the php/apache user, give me a sec and I will update the answer

Comment: are you on Windows, Mac, Linux ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83122/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-matthew-smart).

Comment: i dont see _www anywhere,  this is a local site by the way